# how to Install an app and afterwards have the initial configuration screen (as a new phone)?

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow

How may i install an app, and have the "startup configuration screen" (where the user selects his language, google accounts, etc) without doing a factory reset?

Comment: See https://android.stackexchange.com/q/137324/96277

Comment: Wait what? Do you want to get configuration screen for that app or configuration screen like when  you buy new phone? Why would you want to trigger that after installing an app?

Comment: no, i want to get the configuration screen afterwards. so that the end user can personalize his phone afterwards.

Comment: i want to trigger that so that the end user doesn't call my service to install the famous app which is built for my company, we aim to install the app before the end user can personalize his phone

Answer (score 0):

You can make that app an system app that will prevent your end user from uninstalling this app and even after an hard reset the app is still active, plus the app is installed before the device is given the end user.

ps you must modify the system for that which will mostly cause a loss of warranty.