# How to restore apps after factory reset finished?

Tags: factory-reset, restore

I just did a factory reset on my Android phone (LG G4). I skipped the "Restore apps" menu during the initial setup. I can't find this menu item anywhere on my phone. Is it still possible to restore apps after I left initial setup screen?

Comment: That looks like the initial Setup Wizard. Possibly related/duplicate: [Trigger Setup Wizard at next boot using command-line](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/137324/44325)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this solution?

1. From any home screen, tap **Apps**.
2. Tap **Settings**.
3. If using Tab view, tap **Menu** > **List view**.
4. Scroll to **DEVICE** and then tap **Backup & reset**.
5. Under **LG BACKUP**, tap **Restore** from backup.
6. Locate and tap the backup.
7. Tap **Start** to begin the restore. This may take several minutes.
8. After the restore completes, tap **Done**.
9. The phone reboots to complete the restore.

([Source](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-28973#steps4))

Comment: It lists "Google Drive" as a backup storage but it found no backups.

Comment: Where the backup was stored? SD card or GDrive? It allows you to restore from different sources except gdrive?

Comment: I did not back up anything manually. The initial setup screen gives you the option to restore apps. I skipped this process and this is what I'd like to run now.

Comment: Are you sure that a backup was made? By the way, it may be possible that you can perform the app restore only during the initial configuration, like in iOS when using _Move to iOS_.