# How to restore SMS from Google One backup

Tags: sms, restore, google-one

My Google Pixel 5a suddenly stopped working and I bought a Moto G84 as a replacement. I used the "without device" restore which reinstalled my apps but I don't have any of my SMS messages.

Is there a way to restore that too? On the Google One app, it says my device backup has 131 MB of SMS & MMS messages.

Comment: AFAIK, the backup can only be restored during the Setup Wizard. Possibly related: [How to re-enable first-time setup at next boot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/79609/44325)